# Why is Collection's .addAll slower than manually adding?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I ran two test cases (multiple times), and it seems that iteratively adding values to my lists is faster than using `addAll`

```
String[] rawArgs = new String[]{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};

// More efficient - 894 ns
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : rawArgs) {
    list.add(s);
}


// Less efficient - 1340 ns
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(rawArgs));
```

I get notes through my IDE, as well as other people, that the latter way is the "proper" way to convert an array to that data structure. But if it's actually slower than the first, what advantage is there (some obscure type safety?), and for what reason should I be using the second?

**Edit**  - Code benchmarking:

JVM Warming up, recreate the main class object first:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Internet test;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        test = new Internet(); // JVM warmup
    }
    test = new Internet();
    test.printOutput();
}
```

I simply take the system nanotime at both ends of the operation:

```
start = System.nanoTime();
/* function */
end = System.nanoTime();
result = end - start;
```

Wherein the test case, there are individual fields for each start/end, and results are calculated post-operation (The JVM is also preemptively warmed up by cycling instances before running the tests).

**Edit 2** - Benchmarking with larger collections

After some testing (using Integer instead, not going to hand-write all the numbers), it appears larger collections is indeed slower:

With 100 numbers:

```
First operation: 18759ns
Second operation: 2680ns
Total operation: 21439ns
```

Comment: How are you benchmarking your code?

Comment: Could it be the creation of the extra `List` object that is returned by `Arrays.asList`?

Comment: @RohitJain I'll update the question

Comment: Ok, now try with a hundred elements array, then with one thousand (micro benchmarks are the root of all evil).

Comment: @rgettman That was a potential thought, but `Arrays` simply wraps the array in a static (fake) ArrayList class that is immutable, it doesn't construct an entirely new list.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly I'll run that and update the question

Comment: @Rogue, yes it does use an ArrayList wrapper (not java.util.ArrayList,  though I'm not sure how that's "fake"), but it still has to construct an additional object.

Comment: @Taylor I meant "fake" in how you described, meaning it wasn't java.util :)

Comment: Your benchmark is flawed but the result is probably correct. `Arrays.asList`+`addAll` will create a number of small objects.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The for-each loop resolves to the equivalent of

```
for (int i = 0; i < rawArgs.length; i++) {
  list.add(rawArgs[i]);
}
```

...whereas the implementation of `ArrayList.addAll` actually calls `toArray()`, so it ends up calling `Arrays.asList(rawArgs).toArray()`, which makes a redundant copy.  That said, it also does a `System.arraycopy`, which may end up making it faster than the for loop -- it could go either way, and according to some of the other benchmarks, it may actually go differently in different contexts.

The [`Collections.addAll(Collection<E>, E...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29) static method is actually intended to address this specific issue and be faster than `addAll(Arrays.asList))`, as explicitly stated in its Javadoc.

Comment: Have you looked into the src code of Arrays.asList(), There is no iterator. It calls the constructor of java.util.Arrays.ArrayList (not java.util.ArrayList)

Comment: @AlexWien: `Arrays.asList` inherits the `iterator()` method from `AbstractList`, which _does_ get called.

Comment: @AlexWien That list implements Iterable.  If it's not using an iterator, what's it doing?

Comment: @AlexWien: Actually, you were right in a way, though not the way you intended.  (`ArrayList.addAll` calls `toArray()`, not `iterator()`.) Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks. The number of elements also seemed to be suspect, but the `Collections.addAll` is also a nice touch!

Comment: java.util.ArrayList.toArray copies the array, where java.util.Arrays.ArrayList calls array.clone, however even if it did use an iterator would also have concurrent modification protections. Therefore if the collection you are adding is a list and is locally owned than the fastest approach would be to use an index iterator.

Answer (score 9):

I think `Collection.addAll()` is faster for at least two reasons:

For `ArrayList`

1. It uses `ensureCapacityInternal(size + numNew);` so, if the added List is big, and in a manual add it will be called many times, but in this case it will be called once, with necessary capacity.
2. It uses `System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);` method for copying, which is a native and high performance method.

Comment: So why downvote, please explain, if you have more relevant opinion that my explanation is not true.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a benchmark, with slightly more elements in the array. Results clearly shows that the `addAll` approach wins by margin:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] rawArgs = new String[]{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};

    /******** WARM UP JVM *********/

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        arrayToListLoop(rawArgs);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        arrayToListAddAll(rawArgs);
    }


    /** Actual measurement **/      
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        arrayToListLoop(rawArgs);
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println((end - start) / 1000);

    start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        arrayToListAddAll(rawArgs);
    }
    end = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println((end - start) / 1000);
}

public static void arrayToListLoop(String[] arr) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : arr) {
        list.add(s);
    }
}

public static void arrayToListAddAll(String[] arr) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
}
```

**Results:**

1 First Run:

```
2280
812
```

2 Second Run:

```
1336
613
```

3 Third Run:

```
2088
751
```

Comment: I ran this and got opposite results. (Java 1.6/Hotspot 64-bit server.) Also if I change it so that both ArrayLists are instantiated as `new ArrayList<String>(arr.length)` I get something around `300, 2050`. Though occasionally the loop add takes a very long time (~6000us) which I wonder about.

Comment: I believe you are correct in the idea of number of elements, per my updated snippet at the bottom :)

Comment: @Radiodef Yes, if you run it by passing the `arr.length` parameter, it will be a bit faster, as there won't be any extra array created during addition of newer elements. I ran the benchmark on Java 8 64-bit machine.

Comment: I wonder what the difference is. I tried making the warmup longer which does cut the time for addAll down a bit but the loop is still faster.

Comment: @Radiodef May be they have updated `addAll` method on Java 8. Will have to check the source code for both of them.

Answer (score 3):

I tried repeating this experiment with a large number of iterations and had different results to you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] rawArgs = new String[]{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : rawArgs) {
            list.add(s);
        }
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("add():    " + (end - start));

    start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(rawArgs));
    }
    end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("addAll(): " + (end - start));

}
```

The results:

```
add():    310726674
addAll(): 233785566
```

The exact numbers vary, but `addAll` is *always* faster on my JVM (Sun JDK 1.7 running on Windows). The order with which the two are run makes no difference either (I tried both ways) so it's not to do with warming up. If you increase the number of elements, the results are even more dramatic, possibly because the array behind the ArrayList has to be resized (hence an additional arraycopy).

Comment: Possibly because you are running it 10000000 times, while the OP seems to only run it once.

Comment: I added the warmup I used, but it appears that the number of elements may have been the suspect case

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches for timing benchmarks + as other people note, you should warm up JVM before making your real calculations. I personally never decide when benchmark timings are less than 1 sec and I am trying to create a bigger problem to see the actual results. So,

If your timings are too small (some ns or ms) you then have to increase the problem's size, for instance in your case add N elements, e.g N>1000.

```
 int size = 10000;
 String[] rawArgs = new String[size];
 //add some elements for this test
 for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
     rawArgs[i] = String.valueOf(i);
 }
```

To test with smaller sizes you always have to warm up JVM (take some test measurements before the actual measurement) and create a loop to measure multiple runs of your problem and then divide the total time with the number of these loop-repetitions. For instance,

```
 //after the warm up try the following
 int repetitions = 1000;
 start = System.nanoTime();
 for (int i=0; i<repetitions; i++) {
     //your calculations
 }
 end = System.nanoTime();
 System.out.println("Cost per repetition: " + (end - start)/repetitions);
```